# Can a feebleminded creature use spell-like abilities?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

Can a creature that's affected by [*feeblemind*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feeblemind/) continue using its spell-like abilities?

Feeblemind doesn't explicitly rule out using spell-like abilities, but normally only creatures that have some intelligence/charisma have spell-like abilities so maybe feeblemind does prevent them? But then again no spell components are necessary for using the abilities.

Comment: Question here: which spell-like ability do you mean here in particular, that grants you a spell without needing any components?

Comment: @procra Spell-Like Abilities never require any components.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from the rules for spell-like abilities:

> Spell-like abilities are magical and work just like spells (though **they are not spells** and so have no verbal, somatic, focus, or material components).

As you've stated, *feeblemind* prevents you from using spells but does not explicitly rule out spell-like abilities.

Reading the rest of the spell-like ability rules, there does not seem to be a minimum Charisma requirement to use a spell-like ability.

So, Rules As Written, a creature that's affected by *feeblemind* can continue to use its spell-like abilities.  Note that the save DC of these effects will be quite low since they will be based off the creature's new CHA mod of -5.

Answer (score -1):

### I would argue they cant, tho it depends on the actual ability

The description of the spell gives a little indirect information about that.

> The affected creature is unable to use Intelligence– or Charisma-based skills, cast spells, understand language, or communicate coherently

As most spell-like abilities work similar to a spell, often by reducing the needed components and also limiting the number of usages per day, if that creature can't cast spells it shouldn't be able to use spell-like abilities also. Still if the spell is a very simple low-graded one, your DM might make an exception but one needs to remember the remaining components as in most cases there are some.

---

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack exchange! This looks like a solid first answer. However, answers are not there to ask questions of your own. Additionally, the answer would benefit from some additional factual backup.